# Is there any guarantee that created_at and updated_at are equal right after the first save?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I'm exploring [Rails' source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L29) but I can't find exactly when `created_at` and `updated_at` are set, so I'm unable to answer the question myself.

Comment: This is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb).

Comment: @maxd You should have posted this comment as an answer, so you would receive the rep you deserved. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From rails source [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/63aac338332a06d3c9e28dde7954679703ec7620/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb):

timestamp.rb

```
module ActiveRecord
  # Active Record automatically timestamps create and update operations if the table has fields
  # named created_at/created_on or updated_at/updated_on.
  #
  # Timestamping can be turned off by setting
  #   <tt>ActiveRecord::Base.record_timestamps = false</tt>
  #
  # Timestamps are in the local timezone by default but you can use UTC by setting
  #   <tt>ActiveRecord::Base.default_timezone = :utc</tt>
  module Timestamp
    def self.included(base) #:nodoc:
      base.alias_method_chain :create, :timestamps
      base.alias_method_chain :update, :timestamps

      base.class_inheritable_accessor :record_timestamps, :instance_writer => false
      base.record_timestamps = true
    end

    private
      def create_with_timestamps #:nodoc:
        if record_timestamps
          t = self.class.default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now
          write_attribute('created_at', t) if respond_to?(:created_at) && created_at.nil?
          write_attribute('created_on', t) if respond_to?(:created_on) && created_on.nil?

          write_attribute('updated_at', t) if respond_to?(:updated_at) && updated_at.nil?
          write_attribute('updated_on', t) if respond_to?(:updated_on) && updated_on.nil?
        end
        create_without_timestamps
      end

      def update_with_timestamps(*args) #:nodoc:
        if record_timestamps && (!partial_updates? || changed?)
          t = self.class.default_timezone == :utc ? Time.now.utc : Time.now
          write_attribute('updated_at', t) if respond_to?(:updated_at)
          write_attribute('updated_on', t) if respond_to?(:updated_on)
        end
        update_without_timestamps(*args)
      end
  end
end
```